# What tools can create a clickable dot/bubble for a user tutorial on a website?

Tags: web-development

When first using [Slack](https://slack.com/) and [FullStory](https://www.fullstory.com/), there are hovering dots that appear over features, which you can click to get an explanation of the feature. What tool is used for those tutorials, or what could be used for similar or same effect?

Comment: Could you possibly describe this a bit better please? If I understand you correctly, to see this in action, we must sign up to the site? If it's hard to explain, can you make an animated GIF? You can use Licecap to record the screen and make a gif! :)

Comment: OK, I'll grab a screenshot at the very least when I find a way to reset the tutorial :)